HTML Designer in Visual Studio Community 22
I'm new to Visual Studio, so I'm experimenting. I created a simple html index page in VS Community 22 using html code. I understand there is a visual design tool for html like there used to be in the discontinued Microsoft Expression Web.
How do I open the index.html in design view (I in the visual editor). If this is not possible then could I use a Web Form page to designa static html page?
I have searched the internet for 2 days but no one actually addresses the question.
Many thanks.
I have searched the internet for 2 days looking for a solution. I simply want to open a static html page in desgin view in VS Community 22.
